# Where to store User object after signing in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am building a simple Twitter clone app. Basically you sign in with your username and see all the posts from your friends. I'm using core data for user and post entities.

So far I've managed to implement authentication, but I don't know where to store the user object once user successfully signs in. I'm thinking maybe save it as a property of AppDelegate so it can be accessed from any viewcontrollers, but was wondering if this was the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might have to access the user details from multiple locations within your app. Rather than overload the app delegate with model behavior, you should store user information in a model class. Some developers (myself included) use the singleton pattern to create a model class (or in a more complex app, a model class and a public interface that interfaces with multiple other model classes behind the scenes) where such information can be stored, retrieved, and optionally persisted if required.

Comment: Currently I have a User class which syncs with Core data, and I added a `current_user` property of `User` type to AppDelegate, so I can call it like this: `User *user = [self appDelegate].current_user` (assuming that `appDelegate` function returns the main AppDelegate). How can I modify this to follow your advice?

Comment: Xcode 5 puts CoreData-related properties and code in the appdelegate class when you are creating a new project, but I have chosen to move that code into a separate model class. If you did the same, your model class would similarly have a current_user property. The benefit with a distinct model class may not be immediate, but I feel it's a more scalable and MVC-compliant approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass the user object by itself, or with other object in a larger Context object, and then assign that to each ViewController as needed.

E.g. of a context class

```
@interface MyContextClass
@property (nonatomic) MyUserClass *user;
@property nonatomic) Settings *settings;
@end
```

Then, on any UIViewController, have a property for this Context object.

```
@interface MyViewController
@property (nonatomic) MyContextClass *context;
#end
```

This is an example of dependency injection, and allows you to test different view controllers with different users/contexts/locals, etc, without having to be tied to one singleton.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSUserDefault for this.

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [userDefaults setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
 [userDefaults setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
```

and get it out as:

```
 NSString username = [userDefaults objectsForKey:@"username"];
 NSString password = [userDefaults objectsForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: Please, NEVER save a users password in the user defaults. That's what the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) is for!